# torch.nn.DataParallel with torch.autograd.grad in loss function fails

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, autograd

I have a neural network model that represents the surface of an object. For this to work, the gradients are calculated in the loss function (because for example it's a property of signed distance fields (sdfs) that the gradient is always unit length).
The loss function is the one from [SIREN](https://vsitzmann.github.io/siren/) for sdfs and defined as

```
def sdf(model_output, gt):
    gt_sdf = gt['sdf']
    gt_normals = gt['normals']

    coords = model_output['model_in']
    pred_sdf = model_output['model_out'].to(torch.float32)

    gradient = diff_operators.gradient(pred_sdf, coords)

    # Wherever boundary_values is not equal to zero, we interpret it as a boundary constraint.
    sdf_constraint = torch.where(gt_sdf != -1, pred_sdf, torch.zeros_like(pred_sdf))
    inter_constraint = torch.where(gt_sdf != -1, torch.zeros_like(pred_sdf), torch.exp(-1e2 * torch.abs(pred_sdf)))
    normal_constraint = torch.where(gt_sdf != -1, 1 - F.cosine_similarity(gradient, gt_normals, dim=-1)[..., None],
                                    torch.zeros_like(gradient[..., :1]))
    grad_constraint = torch.abs(gradient.norm(dim=-1) - 1)

    return {'sdf': torch.abs(sdf_constraint).mean() * 3e3,
            'inter': inter_constraint.mean() * 1e2,
            'normal_constraint': normal_constraint.mean() * 1e2,
            'grad_constraint': grad_constraint.mean() * 5e1}
```

and the gradient calculation uses `torch.autograd.grad`:

```
def gradient(y, x, grad_outputs=None):
    if grad_outputs is None:
        grad_outputs = torch.ones_like(y)
    grad = torch.autograd.grad(y, [x], grad_outputs=grad_outputs, create_graph=True)[0]
    return grad
```

Now I wanted to parallelise the training by implementing `torch.nn.DataParallel`. I get the following **error**:

```
RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior.
```

Is it possible to use `torch.nn.DataParallel` with gradient calculation in the loss function and what do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation of [`nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel.html#torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel):

> This module doesn’t work with `torch.autograd.grad()` (i.e. it will only work if gradients are to be accumulated in `.grad` attributes of parameters).

It also recommends to use [`torch.distributed.autograd.backward`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/rpc.html#torch.distributed.autograd.backward) and [`torch.distributed.optim.DistributedOptimizer`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/rpc.html#torch.distributed.optim.DistributedOptimizer).

Also in the documentation of [`torch.distributed`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#autograd-enabled-communication-primitives) it recommends using `gloo` backend:

> Please notice that currently the only backend where all the functions are guaranteed to work is `gloo`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I am not using ```nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel``` exactly for that reason, but ```nn.parallel.DataParallel```.